# Merge model association data rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model `User` that has many reports.
Each `Report` has many `Records`

I want to merge 2 reports by making all the records report_id as the first one from the second one.

Currently I have done it like this but I think there is a faster way, this takes too long!

```
    reports = params[:reports]
    to_merge_report = Report.find(params[:to_merge_report])

    reports.each do |report, value|
        r = Report.find(value)
        r.records.each do |record|
            record.report = to_merge_report
            record.save!
        end
        r.destroy
    end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just change the report_id in the second report's records, so that each of those records points to the first report instead of the second report.

First, set `id_1` equal to the first report's ID and `id_2` equal to the second report's ID.

Then...

```
first_report = Report.find(id_1)
first_set_of_records = first_report.records

second_report = Report.find(id_2)
second_set_of_records = second_report.records

second_set_of_records.each |record|
  record.report_id = first_report.id
  record.save
end
```

Comment: Yep that's what I had but scaled for many reports to be merged into one!

Comment: If your question is how to update many records at once, then this might help: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200235/rails-save-collection-of-updated-records-all-at-once)