# Receiving already loaded object from find_by method of ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have the following models

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :parent
end
```

What I want to do is changing a child object by `parent.children.find_or_initialize_by()` and modify the child object, then save it by `parent.save`. But the children doesn't get saved. Here's the code.

```
# prepare a parent with a child
p = Parent.new({:name=>'parent'})
p.children << Child.new({:name => 'child'})
p.save

# modify and save child
p = Parent.first
c = p.children.find_or_initialize_by({:name=>'child'}) #=> returns the child already created above
c.name = 'new child'
p.save #=> children aren't saved
```

I know this is because `find_by` method always returns a new object rather than the one already loaded. But it seems more natural to me if the code above works because the method is invoked through `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`. Am I missing anything to get this to work? Or are there any reasons that `find_by` on `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` have to work as it currently does?

(I know I can save the modified child by `c.save`, but I want to save the child through `parant.save`, because I want the errors on child object to be referenced by parent.errors.)

Comment: I think you can find your answer here: [click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200235/rails-save-collection-of-updated-records-all-at-once)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but looks like that's not what I want..

Comment: you can try to do `p.children.save`